# Truncate the task name in emacs mode-line

Tags: emacs, org-mode

While org-clock-in a task, the task name will be shown on the mode-line. But some of my task names are too long. Is there any function to truncate the display name in the mode line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can tune this according to your taste:

```
(setq org-clock-heading-function
      (lambda ()
        (let ((str (nth 4 (org-heading-components))))
          (if (> (length str) 6)
              (substring str 0 6)))))
```

Comment: I have just submitted an edit to prevent errors in the event that the headline string is already less than 6 characters.